# Accessing single field from object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor with MongoDB and can't seem to figure out how to access a single field from the objects in an object array.

My documents:

```
  {
     "_id" : "p6c4cSTb3cHWaJqpG",
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-11T11:30:11.820Z"),
     "username" : "admin",
     "contacts" : [ 
         {
            "when" : ISODate("2016-05-11T11:30:32.350Z"),
            "who" : "4YBufbE9PByJBkasy"
         }, 
         {
            "when" : ISODate("2016-05-25T11:52:49.745Z"),
            "who" : "z792kEEYbxyzyEAKp"
         }, 
         {
            "when" : ISODate("2016-05-26T13:47:43.439Z"),
            "who" : "4YBufbE9PByJBkasy"
         }, 
         {
            "when" : ISODate("2016-05-26T13:48:22.828Z"),
            "who" : "4YBufbE9PByJBkasy"
         }
     ]
}
```

I want to check if a `userId` is in any of the objects, specifically in the `who` fields.

My Server-side code:

```
 var me = Meteor.userId();
 var findMe = Meteor.users.findOne(me);

 if (_.include(findMe.contacts, {who: 4YBufbE9PByJBkasy})){
        console.log("found in array");
    }else{
        console.log("Not found in array");
    }
}
```

I have tried this several different ways, but came up with nothing.

When I `console.log(findMe.contacts);`, it returns the whole array like it should. but when I try to `console.log(findMe.contacts.who);`, it returns `undefined`.

Just need some direction on how to access the field of the object array. Thanks!

Comment: `findMe.contacts` is an array, it has no property `who`, in order to access one of the array's elements you have to supply an index like: `findMe.contacts[0].who`

Comment: That makes sense. I tried that, but seeing yours I now realize my syntax was wrong.  So how do I check all objects for a string in the `who` field? Doing something like a `count` on the number of objects then doing a loop through each one seems like more work than necessary, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You can't check each item without checking each item :-)  Also, with a small amount of editing, you could have a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through an array to see whether it contains a value is easily
done with [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var data = {
    "_id" : "p6c4cSTb3cHWaJqpG",
    "createdAt" : "2016-05-11T11:30:11.820Z",
    "username" : "admin",
    "contacts" : [
        {
            "when" : "2016-05-11T11:30:32.350Z",
            "who" : "4YBufbE9PByJBkasy"
        },
        {
            "when" : "2016-05-25T11:52:49.745Z",
            "who" : "z792kEEYbxyzyEAKp"
        },
        {
            "when" : "2016-05-26T13:47:43.439Z",
            "who" : "4YBufbE9PByJBkasy"
        },
        {
            "when" : "2016-05-26T13:48:22.828Z",
            "who" : "4YBufbE9PByJBkasy"
        }
    ]
};

var hascontact = function(contacts, id){
    return contacts.some(function(contact){
        return contact.who === id;
    });
};

console.log(hascontact(data.contacts,'4YBufbE9PByJBkasy'));
console.log(hascontact(data.contacts,'z792kEEYbxyzyEAKp'));
console.log(hascontact(data.contacts,'asdfasdfasdfasdfa'));
```